# jQuery "modify" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

So I recently took a closer look at JavaScript and jQuery and after that stumbled over the Firefox extension called Greasemonkey.

Well, let me explain what I mean with the "modifiy"-event: I've got 2-3 userscripts for a certain page installed which automatically look if the page has changed in any way and if it has, they load the new content and append it to the already loaded page (they modify the DOM).

So basically, my userscript needs to know when that happens but I don't know how I should do that. Are there any jQuery events for that? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var orig;

$(function(){
     orig = getContent();
})

function watchContent() {
     var mod = getContent();
     if (mod != orig){ resetContent(orig); }
     setTimeout(watchContent,1000)
}

function resetContent(html) {
  $("body").append( html );
}

function getContent() {
    return $("body").html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery events if you want the event to apply to new elements you would use the [.live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) method, however jQuery 1.3 doesn't support `blur`, `focus`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `change`, or `submit` events as live events, and it's `change` that you will want to use. (`change`, `submit`, and `blur/focus` are on the [roadmap](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_1.4_Roadmap#Events) for jQuery 1.4)

As an alternative you could use the [liveQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) plugin.

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/GsGOSnFQaa6Ju23Poe8T/
The commented part doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: without seeing the html and the greasemonkey scripts that change it, it's hard to tell.