# "onModify" event for <select>

Tags: jquery

### TL;DR

How can I watch for changes in markup in `<select>` and, more importantly, `<option>` tags?

I **don't** want to listen for the `.change()` event (`onChange`), but I **do** want to listen for any changes in attributes (`disabled="disabled"`), values (`value="foo"`) or text.

### The long version

I'm writing a simple `<select>` replacement plugin for jQuery. As one of the features, I'd like it to dynamically update with the select box. The one feature I'm stuck with is how to watch for events such as another piece of JS changing one of the `<select>`'s `<option>`s by, for example, changing it's text, value or disabled state.

I've found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843318/jquery-modify-event) that provides a solution, however it just sets up a `setTimeout()` to poll the element.

Is there a clean (by which I mean "not using `setTimeout()`) way of watching for modifications of elements, specifically the `<option>`s inside a dropdown select control? The three main things I want to watch for are:

- When the text of the option is changed.
- When it is disabled or enabled.
- When it's value is changed.

All of these triggered by a piece of JS not related to the plugin I'm writing.

Comment: Unless you can rely on a custom event being triggered in the code that changes the element (e.g. `$(selectElem).trigger("modified");`) I think checking on a regular interval will be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks @JamesAllardice. It's a strange requirement, but it would have been nice to be able to come up with a non-polling solution. `setInterval()` it is.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice to have the ability to do things like this neatly. Unfortunately, until browsers catch up (and old ones die out completely) it's not going to be reliable to bind to `DOMSubtreeModified`.

Comment: To be clear, and perhaps a little pedantic, "markup" never changes once it has arrived. Markup is what you send from the server, but a DOM is what we get the play with once your markup has been parsed. So what you're watching for is mutations of DOM elements, not changes in tags. There, I've said my peace. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other JS snippets won't necessarily fire a dom event, so event listeners aren't going to help you much.  In fact, for your examples... the only one that will ever fire a dom event is if the value is changed.  You could write some fancy selectors for jquery's `on()` method to check enabled/disabled, though.

In short, the setTimeout (or rather setInterval) may be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subscribe to the dom subtree modified event like so:

```
$('select').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  if ($(this).is('option')) {
    // Your code here
  }
});
```

**Update**

Since support for DOMSubtreeModified is a little... flaky at the moment, lets give the following a go (NB untested!):

```
(function($) {
  var nativeSupport = false;
  var parent = $('<div></div>');
  parent.bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    nativeSupport = true;
  });
  parent.append($('<div></div>'));
  if (nativeSupport) {
    $.fn.subtreeModified = function(onModified) {
      $(this).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', onModified);
    };
  } else {
    $.fn.subtreeModified = function(onModified) {
      var self = $(this);
      var html = self.html();
      var checkForModifications = function() {
        var currentHtml = self.html();
        if (html !== currentHtml) {
          onModified.apply(self, []);
          html = currentHtml;
        }
      };
      window.setInterval(checkForModifications, 100);
    };
  }
})(window.jQuery);
```

Which would then be useable like so:

```
$('select').subtreeModified(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: As I've stated in my comment to seth's answer, I **don't** wnat to watch for the `.change()` event, but any changes to the properties of the `<option>` elements themselves.

Comment: @JamWaffles Answer updated, apologies - I misread the question originally.

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified is IE9+ (and even then is buggy, because it doesn't do appendChild).

Comment: @rich.okelly Not a problem. I got excited at first, as this is a great way to do it, but I was looking for browser support. Thankfully John Green piped up and now I'm sad again.

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike Thanks - I was just looking for the browser support for this event. A shame it's only IE9+, and should we ever expect anything in IE _not_ to be buggy?

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike & JamWaffles - Answer now updated to delegate to native support if available and fallback to polling if not (thanks for pointing out support and bugginess of DOMSubtreeModified event JG-PS), please feel free to add comments on subtreeModified method and any other gotchas that need to be catered for!

Comment: @rich.okelly - I haven't done any testing or anything... but you're expecting the event stack to fire through on the append, which I wouldn't think would be particularly reliable.  Check out this article:  http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/ - along with this solution: http://www.strictly-software.com/eventsupport.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `onChange` event...

Comment: I already do, but the `onChange` event only fires when one of the select's options is clicked either by the user or from JS. I want to watch for changes in _markup_.